# .NET Equivalent of MD5.hex() in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm trying to connect to a website I made with auth that uses MD5.hex(password) to encrypt the password before sending it to the PHP. How could I achieve the same encryption in C#?

EDIT1:

Javascript (YUI Library):

```
pw = MD5.hex(pw);
this.chap.value = MD5.hex(pw + this.token.value);
```

C#.NET

```
string pw = getMD5(getHex(getMD5(getHex(my_password)) + my_token));
```

Utility:

```
public string getMD5(string input)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

        // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
        byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));

        // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
        // and create a string.
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
        // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        // Return the hexadecimal string.
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public string getHex(string asciiString)
    {
        string hex = "";
        foreach (char c in asciiString)
        {
            int tmp = c;
            hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
        }
        return hex;
    }
```

Comment: @Gio: you probably knew this, but just in case: C# has no encryption support at all. However, the .NET Framework does, as Mitch answered below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using .NET's [MD5 Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx) in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace.

The link above contains a short code example; you might also want to check out Jeff Attwood's CodeProject article [.NET Encryption Simplified](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/SimpleEncryption.aspx).

Comment: Silly me, I didn't go over the utility functions I copypasted and realized that the MD5 already hexed the data.